# Is it possible to get the gameobject nested child from parent with script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to get the gameobject Nested Child from Parent ?

The Map Gameobject is like below :

```
ListProcess (ListProcessItem1) => item1 => 1 => ItemIcon
```

For example Iam using this code :

```
itemslot = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("ListProcessItem1").gameObject;
GameObject item = itemslot.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
GameObject child = item.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
GameObject sitemImage = child.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
```

When I run the code I got an error:

```
UnityException: Transform child out of bounds
LakeMainProcess.generatePrize1 () (at Assets/script/fishing/LakeMainProcess.cs:48)
LakeMainProcess.Start () (at Assets/script/fishing/LakeMainProcess.cs:21)
```

*Note :
I just can reach until the gameobject ( 1 ) . The gameobject ( ItemIcon ) Got an error.*

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your chunk with this:

```
Debug.Log("A " + GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("ListProcessItem1") == null);
var itemslot = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("ListProcessItem1").gameObject;

Debug.Log("B " + itemslot.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0) == null);
GameObject item = itemslot.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;

Debug.Log("C " + item.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0) == null);
GameObject child = item.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;

Debug.Log("D " + child.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0) == null);
GameObject sitemImage = child.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
```

It will tell you what object could not be found. I bet it's `FindGameObjectWithTag`, are you sure this object has this exact tag ?

Alternatively and more simply use:

```
var ico = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ListProcessItem1").transform.FindChild("item1/1/ItemIcon").GetComponent<WhateverYouNeed>();
```

Comment: Yes @izeed, I got missing something. The gameobject not start at ListProcess. But it start at item1 => ListProcessItem1. Thank you.